# Does CodeExample.com have rights to copy SO posts?

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

If you navigate to the following link, you will see that a question I originally posted to SO has been copied to CodeExample.com.

https://codexample.org/questions/385320/why-doesn-t-microsoft-skydrive-download-multiple-files-even-though-ms-example-shows-it-wl-download.c

Is CodeExample.com an SO site?  Is CodeExample.com authorized to do this?
Just thought SO might be interested in this.

BTW -- Here's my original posted question on SO:
[Why doesn't Microsoft Skydrive download multiple files even though MS example shows it? (wl.download)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913274/why-doesnt-microsoft-skydrive-download-multiple-files-even-though-ms-example-sh)

Comment: Everyone in the world has the right to copy the user submitted content on SO, subject to a few restrictions (namely proper citation and applying the same licence to the copied content).